# Instantiating a protocol properly to send a message on python/twisted

Tags: python, client-server, twisted

I am working with a few client/server examples in python to set up a simple chat-based client.

I am having issues with the GUI, when I try to send a message:

```
class ChatFrame(wx.Frame):
  def __init__(self):
    wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent=None, title="Game Client")
    self.protocol = EchoProtocol  # twisted Protocol

    sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
    self.text = wx.TextCtrl(self, style=wx.TE_MULTILINE | wx.TE_READONLY)
    self.ctrl = wx.TextCtrl(self, style=wx.TE_PROCESS_ENTER, size=(300, 25))

    sizer.Add(self.text, 5, wx.EXPAND)
    sizer.Add(self.ctrl, 0, wx.EXPAND)
    self.SetSizer(sizer)
    self.ctrl.Bind(wx.EVT_TEXT_ENTER, self.send)

  def send(self, evt):
    self.protocol.sendLine(str(self.ctrl.GetValue()))
    self.ctrl.SetValue("")
```

The problem is that when I send the message, I get the following error:

```
TypeError: unbound method sendLine() must be called with EchoProtocol instance as first argument (got str instance instead)
```

I also tried changing the line

self.protocol = EchoProtocol  # twisted Protocol

To:

protocol = EchoProtocol()
   self.protocol = protocol

The error I get here is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "client.py", line 32, in send
    self.protocol.sendLine(str(self.ctrl.GetValue()))
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/twisted/protocols/basic.py", line 625, in sendLine
    return self.transport.write(line + self.delimiter)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'write'
```

My question is how can I invoke the send event and send the message correctly?

Comment: Did you read the client howto?  https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/howto/clients.html